# Filter length in a Filtered-OFDM system

Tags: fft, filters, ofdm

In a filtered-OFDM system, lets say we have the following parameters:

```
NFFT=256;  % number of IFFT/FFT points
Ncp=52;    % cyclic prefix length in samples
Nsc=120;   % number of data subcarriers
```

The remaining subcarriers (NFFT-Nsc=136) are unused carriers, and 68 on either side of the OFDM symbol.

So by using these parameters and their values, if we construct a filter to be applied into the IFFT symbol just after the CP addition process, how can we select the filter length? Does it depends on the CP length?

Comment: filter length can well exceed the guard interval length in the form of CP.

Answer (score 0):

The number of taps you'll need depends on the filter's spectral properties; as far as I know, filtered OFDM doesn't dictate specific filter properties per se, so there's no specific length that resulting filter would have.

Note that there might be limits to filter length, to avoid ISI; the filter state shouldn't still contain a previous symbol's energy when it passes the next CP's beginning. As everywhere, this might lead to a trade–off; also note that F-OFDM receivers often implement the inverse filter to the transmit filter, so that this source of ISE might be mitigated.

Comment: thanks @Marcus Müller. Could you also please explain how we use the above parameters ,NFFT=256, Ncp=52 and Nsc=120 when designing a sinc filter?

Comment: um, no. I can't do that, because, again, there's nothing you say about what that filter should do. Generally: Sinc filters are just rectangular "cutouts" in the other domain, so I doubt this is something you want to "design", it's just something that "happens" if you don't filter. NB: a convolution of two sincs always is the "wider" one, so filtering OFDM (which is, spectrally, a sinc filterbank) with a sinc per se doesn't sound like a smart idea to me.